# Introduction does not appear in the Contents page (thesis)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, thesis

I am currently using the following template to write a thesis: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/iit-bombay-unofficial-latex-ph-dot-d-thesis-template/fybkvhqjqqsf .
I want to add an introduction and want the introduction to appear on the Contents page. I did this the following way: I created a chapter called Introduction, but I do not want the introduction to be numbered. In the chapter "Introduction" I coded:

```
\chapter*{Introduction}\doublespacing % Main chapter title
```

And in the file "main" I added the following code before the thesis chapters:

```
\input{Chapters/Introduction/Introduction}
```

The problem with this is that Introduction is not appearing in the Contents page. How should I proceed to have a link to the Introduction in the Contents page?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `*` from `chapter`? In its current form  you are explicity writing to not to include the introduction chapter in the file of contents.

Comment: Yes, but then the Introduction will be numbered. I want Introduction in the Contents page, but without a number. Otherwise, the 1st chapter of the thesis, will have the number 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `chapter*`, you have to add manually the chapter to the table of contents. At least for me, this also fixed the number for the chapters (i.e., Chapter 1 starts with 1 not with 2). After declaring the chapter, you just need to write `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`.

Do note that, if your Introduction has sections, you must do the same for each section, so they do not appear in the TOC with the 0.X numbering.

What I got:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction} % Manuallz add chanter in table of contents
    \section*{Intro section}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Intro section} % Manuallz add chanter in table of contents
    
    \chapter{Chapter one}
    \section{Ch1 section}
    
    \chapter{Chapter two}
    \section{Ch2 section}
    
\end{document}
```